# Is it possible to open specific file types in different windows in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, header-files

I am aware that you can drag code tabs to your second screen and maximize them, so you have a new window.

Now i use the second screen for my `.h` files and my first screen for `.cpp` files. 
Is it possible, that VS opens the `.h` files per default in the second window, so i dont have to drag them around?

Comment: Visual studio will open the file in the window you last clicked, so just click inside the secondary window before opening an `h` file.

Comment: Doesn't work if you have the solution explorer in the main window and you want to open a file in the second window.
With selecting the file, the focus jumps to the window with the solution explorer.